# How to modify the values in a dataframe based on the values from another dataframe in an efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have 2 dataframes like so:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Col1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
        'Col2':[3.409836, 2.930693, 2.75, 3.140845, 2.971429, 2.592593, 2.6, 3.1875, 2.857143, 0.714286]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])

data2 = {'Col1':['B', 'F', 'I'],
         'Col2':[23.45, 32.57, 19.85]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
```

[image]

I want to modify the values of `Col2` in `df1` with the values from `df2`. This is my code to do that:

```
for i in range(len(df2)):
    for j in range(len(df1)):
        if df2['Col1'][i]==df1['Col1'][j]:
            df1['Col2'][j]=df2['Col2'][i]
```

The code works:

[image]

But the problem is, this code would be slow for large dataframes as it has complexity `O(len(df1)*len(df2))`. How do I merge the 2 dataframes in a faster, more efficient way?

I tried merging the dataframes using outer join, but it does not produce the correct result - it keeps both values:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')
```

[image]

An inner join produces a blank dataframe, a left join produces the same dataframe as `df1`, and a right join produces the same dataframe as `df2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If working only with one column use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1['Col2'] = df1['Col1'].map(df2.set_index('Col1')['Col2']).fillna(df1['Col2'])
print (df1)
  Col1       Col2
0    A   3.409836
1    B  23.450000
2    C   2.750000
3    D   3.140845
4    E   2.971429
5    F  32.570000
6    G   2.600000
7    H   3.187500
8    I  19.850000
9    J   0.714286
```

If multiple columns is possible use `merge` with left join and specified column `Col1`:

```
cols = df1.columns.difference(['Col1'])
orig_cols = [f'{x}_' for x in cols]

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='Col1', suffixes=('_',''))
print (df)
  Col1     Col2_   Col2
0    A  3.409836    NaN
1    B  2.930693  23.45
2    C  2.750000    NaN
3    D  3.140845    NaN
4    E  2.971429    NaN
5    F  2.592593  32.57
6    G  2.600000    NaN
7    H  3.187500    NaN
8    I  2.857143  19.85
9    J  0.714286    NaN
```

Then replace missing values of added column by original columns and last remove them:

```
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(df[orig_cols].rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('_')))
df = df.drop(orig_cols, axis=1)

print (df)
  Col1       Col2
0    A   3.409836
1    B  23.450000
2    C   2.750000
3    D   3.140845
4    E   2.971429
5    F  32.570000
6    G   2.600000
7    H   3.187500
8    I  19.850000
9    J   0.714286
```

Comment: Could you please also edit the answer to add the solution for using multiple columns?

Comment: @Kristada673 - I try do it, please check it.

Comment: Awesome! Just 1 more thing - how do I add another column called `Col3` in `df1` which will say either `modified` if the value has been modified according to `df2`, or `original` if its not?

Comment: @Kristada673 - I think in `merge` is parameter for it - `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='Col1', suffixes=('_',''), indicator=True)`

Comment: @Kristada673 - bith means value is in both df, so replaced

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
df4=df3.Col3.isnull()
df3=pd.merge(df1, df2,how='outer')
df4=df3[df3.Col3.isnull()]
df5=df3[df3.Col3.notnull()]
df5.Col2=df5.Col3
df6=df4.append(df5)
df6=df6.drop('Col3',axis=1)
```

df6 is the output you are looking for.